# how to store the output to a log instead of echo

Tags: linux, bash, logging, scripting

I'm working on a script and i want the output to be hidden unless there is a problem. everything is working OK except the file only contains the first few lines of output and everything is still showing in the window.

```
elif [ $input = "3" ]; then  
    echo "enter package name"
    read package
    apt-get build-dep $package
    apt-get install $package -y >> /var/log/installlog
    exitstatus=$(echo $?)
    if [ $exitstatus = "0" ]; then
        figlet Installation Successful
    else
        echo "Failure check /var/log/installlog"
        figlet check now?
        echo "y or n"
        read input2
            if [ $input2 = "y" ]; then
                cat /var/log/installlog
            fi;
    fi;
```

when i check the installlog file i get

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
```

I've tried using the tee command and got similar results

Comment: what exactly does "2>&1" do?

Comment: this kind of works but the terminal still prints "E: Unable to locate package vvhfdjghdrkj
" insteadof putting it in the file

Comment: so far I got this "apt-get install $package -y  2>&1> /var/log/installlog 2>&1" and it works how i want it to in the terminal but for some reason when i run that code in my script it still prints the output. it still puts the output in the file but I dont want it to print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this 2>&1 also in this line

```
      apt-get install $package -y >> /var/log/installlog 2>&1
```

To add stderr also log file.

Comment: i get "bash: $1: ambiguous redirect" when i enter that

Comment: ok so i got it working by putting 2>&1 in both lines so the code is as follows "apt-get install $package -y 2>&1 >> /var/log/installlog 2>&1"  and then the file reads "Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package vvhfdjghdrkj"

Comment: Thanks for the help! @Varun